# Keep only the first and last business day of each month in Excel

Tags: excel

I posted this question combined with a dozen other questions I now solved yet this one still remains, hopefully someone has a smart idea.

Challenge:

I got a spreadsheet with daily stock prices for 500 companies with the goal  to calculate monthly returns. To achieve this I only need the frist and last business/ trading day of each month. As the data covers roughly 20 years the option to delete the days within these two manually isn't really efficient. Any ideas how to do it faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a helper column with a formula to determine whether a day should be kept or not, then filter/delete?

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the idea. So you propose finding out the first and last day, check if that "generated" day in the helper column matches the date in the date column and if yes, keep the entry, otherwise delete it? Sounds like it could work, but wouldn't be pretty :D

Comment: Eh.. does it need to be pretty?

Comment: Apart from helper column, you can also use power query but you need to let us know what is the logic of finding the first and last day per trading period.

Comment: I'll have a look at that @TerryW. Not sure if I understood correctly what you meant by logic but like I said: Before I perform some special regressions I need to caculate monthly returns of the stocks. If you don't have any dividends during the month you can simply divide (the price of the last trading day by the price of the first)-1 to get the monthly returns. If I delete the unnecessary data the spreadsheets contains only 220k data points instead of 2.75 million data points making it easier to handle in later tasks

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output pls.

Comment: I want to know how to determine the `frist and last business/ trading day of each month`? Is it simple as 1st day and 30th or 31st day of each month? Or first Monday and last Friday, or something else? You will still need to use helper column in power query editor but instead of doing that on the actual data table you can do it in the back end and load the *filtered* output without showing any helper columns.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's about the actual first and last trading days of the month. Stock exchange is typically open Monday to Friday but it also should take holidays into consideration as the stock exchange is closed on these days. But doing all the process in the back end is a good idea. I'm completly unfamiliar with power query so that's what I'll have a look at.